# Formula for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am to find the formula for the linear equation:

$T(v_1)=v_2$, $T(v_2)=v_3$, $T(v_3)=v_1$

Where I know the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in R^3$

So far I've set up the following:
$c_1\begin{pmatrix}v_{11}\\v_{12}\\v_{13}\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}v_{21}\\v_{22}\\v_{23}\end{pmatrix}+c_3\begin{pmatrix}v_{31}\\v_{32}\\v_{33}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$

Then made the agumented matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}v_{11} & v_{21} & v_{31} & x_1\\v_{12} & v_{22} & v_{23} & x_2\\v_{13} & v_{32} & v_{33} & x_3\end{pmatrix}$

And used Gauss-Jordan elimination to find values for $c_1, c_2, c_3$

But I am unsure how to move forward from here?

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Let $X$ be the matrix representing $T$, let $A$ be the matrix with columns $v_1,v_2,v_3$, let $B$ be the matrix with columns $v_2,v_3,v_1$, then $XA=B$.

Comment: Thats seems to be getting me an elementary matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 &1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ What can I use this for?

Comment: Check your calculation. I think you're doing something like $AX=B$, not $XA=B$.

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your linear combination helps because you haven't said what $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are!

Instead, I would write the desired 3 by 3 matrix as $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$
And write
$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_{11} \\ v_{12} \\ v_{13}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}av_{11}+ bv_{12}+ cv_{13} \\ dv_{11}+ ev_{12}+ fv_{13}\\ gv_{11}+ hv_{12}+ iv_{13}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}v_{21}\\ v_{22} \\ v_{23}\end{bmatrix}$

So we have the three equations
$av_{11}+ bv_{12}+ cv_{13}= v_{21}$
$dv_{11}+ ev_{12}+ fv_{13}= v_{22}$ and
$gv_{11}+ hv_{12}+ iv_{13}= v_{23}$
for the 9 unknowns, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, and I.

Do the same for the conditions that $T(v_2)= v_3$ and $T(v_3)= v_1$ to get 6 more equations so that you have a total of 9 equations to solve for the 9 unknowns.

Comment: If i try to solve this agumented matrix you examplified using Gauss-Jordan, would'nt that be impossible? Since the three rows are the same and I would'nt be able to get three pivot elements